# AWS EC2 instance upgade - IP changes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm thinking of upgrading my instance type in my AWS EC2. Will the IP change? If so, how do I retain the ip?

P.S I'm referring to the public IP

Comment: The Private IP address will not change, but the Public IP address _will_ change. There is no way to 'keep' it unless the Public IP address is assigned via an Elastic IP address, which is a static IP address.

Comment: @Ernest If you opt for elastic IP address, you will have to incur a certain fee for it,So business wise you have to look at making it cost effective. Just keep that in mind

Comment: @quintumnia elastic IP is free unless you leave it unattached, or leave it attached to a stopped instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Change the instance type - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html):

**Considerations for compatible instance types**

Consider the following when changing the instance type of an existing instance:

- You must stop your Amazon EBS-backed instance before you can change
  its instance type. Ensure that you plan for downtime while your
  instance is stopped. Stopping the instance and changing its instance
  type might take a few minutes, and restarting your instance might
  take a variable amount of time depending on your application's
  startup scripts. For more information, see Stop and start your
  instance.
- When you stop and start an instance, we move the instance to new
  hardware. If your instance has a public IPv4 address, we release the
  address and give your instance a new public IPv4 address. If you
  require a public IPv4 address that does not change, [use an Elastic IP
  address.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)